# Which USB webcam (with microphone and speakers) works for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, microphones, speakers, webcam

I would like to solve three problems with a single (USB) device:

1. Camera
2. Audio-Out
3. Audio-In

I believe more and more of those home monitoring solutions have those things combined into one device (e.g. the Nest Cam).

However, I don't want to have to go through some cloud storage solution and instead get direct access to the audio and video signals, because I would like to use this with a Raspberry Pi (3).

Any recommendations which USB driven camera would work with the Raspberry Pi (3) and also features a microphone and speakers?